# Separating out the last term of a given sequence

Tags: summation, notation

I am suppose to separate the last term of the given sequence.

$$\sum_{j=0}^n2^j$$

my work as shown...
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j\ +\ 2^n$$

Does this appear wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is just the definition of the sum symbol. For $n=2$, for example, $\sum_{j=0}^ 2 2^j=2^0+2^1+2^2=\sum_{j=0}^1 2^j+2^2$. Here $n-1=1$.

Comment: This appears correct to me. To make it clear the $+2^n$ is not inside the sum, you might want to place parentheses around the sum, as in: $$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j\right)+2^n$$

Comment: No, it does not appear wrong

Comment: I'd even add to @Clayton's idea, that you might separate out that "last term" in front, so you write $$2^n + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 2^j,$$ at which point the parentheses are unnecessary. (This doesn't work *quite* so nicely when you have to pull out the first *and* last terms, and it's natural to place those before and after the main sum, but it's still not a bad practice.)